# Is there any way in Joomla to convert any extention of 2.5 to work in 3.0?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I have an extension in joomla which is working very well in version 2.5 ,Is there any short changes for doing to working well this extension in version 3.0?

```
extension name- DJschedule-2.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it work only on Joomla 3.x then read carefully the [backward compatibility issues docu](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2).

As I migrated my extensions I had basically to do:

- Search for *JView* and replace it with *JViewLegacy* in the files
- Convert your view files to support bootstrap in front and back
- Search for DS and replace it with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR (or do it lazy and define DS by yourself)

And the rest of the time I spent hunting for little bugs.

If you want to make it work on both versions then I suggest to have a look on [FOF](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/fof.html), which makes the hard work for you.